# Setting yticks Location Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to create a plot which has y axis exactly same with this :

[image]

And I'm in this situation and everything is ok until this point:

[image]

When i try this lines:

```
ax.set_yticks(range(20,67,10))
ax.set_yticklabels(['20','30','40','50','60'])
```

My graph is becoming this:

[image]

I couldn't understand how to set locations' of yticks properly.

Comment: You do not show a [mcve] of the issue. Hence nobody has any idea how you created this graph. You're thereby wasting the time of people trying to answer.

Comment: I thought i provided enough information, anyway thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want numbers on the axes, **make sure you plot numbers, not strings**. The axis labels would then adjust automatically as desired, or you may use `set_yticks` and `set_yticklabels` as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
import numpy as np
ticks = np.linspace(20, 60, 5)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels([str(int(x)) for x in ticks])
```